# ASP MVC 1 Custom Routing for Folders and SubFolders

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a simple CRUD application using ASP MVC 1 that will store data across multiple tables for multiple student programs. In doing so, I'm trying to figure out how to structure the URL to accommodate each program, their tables, and their actions.

For example, something I am trying to achieve is:

**site.com/StudProg1/Participant/Create** will be the URL for inserting an entry for the Participant Table for Student Program 1

**site.com/StudProg2/Course/**  will be the URL for the Index page for the Course Table for Student Program 2

In my attempt to create custom routes to accommodate this, my Global.asax.cs file stands as follows:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "StudProg1",
            "StudProg1/{pageName}/{action}",
            new { controller = "StudProg1", pageName="Index", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "StudProg2",
            "StudProg2/{pageName}/{action}",
            new { controller = "StudProg2", pageName="Index", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
}
```

Where pageName is supposed to be the table name.

Not surprisingly, the above structure does not return the output I am aiming for (i.e. it always points to the Index page for StudProg).

Additionally, my file directory is structured as such:

```
Views
    StudProg1
        Index
        Participant
            Index
            Create
    StudProg2
        Index
        Courses
            Index
            Create
```

etc.

My question is, how can I improve my routes to correctly achieve the URL structure I desire. Additionally, besides the Microsoft ASP.NET Developer Network Site, are there any good tutorials on custom routes?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be creating a controller for each student program (StudProg1,StudProg2 etc). You can accept that as a parameter.

You need only 2 controlellers, one for Particiant and one for Course.

```
public class ParticipantController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content("Reques for partiicpant index page if needed");
    }
    public ActionResult create(string studentProgram)
    {
        return Content("Partiicpant create for "+studentProgram);
    }
}
public class CourseController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content("Course:");
    }
}
```

and in your RouteConfig's RegisterRoutes method, specify the 2 specific routes before the generic default route.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute("part","{studentProgram}/Participant/{action}",
        new { controller = "Participant", action = "Index" }
    );

   routes.MapRoute("course", "{studentProgram}/Course/{action}",
                       new { controller = "Course", action = "Index" }
   );

   routes.MapRoute("Default",
       "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });        

}
```